# Creating a test project to test classes in another project in Android

Tags: android, testing, android-2.2-froyo

I have a project with many classes and activities. I would like to test some of those classes by creating another project and using them. Is this possible? I tried creating an Android test project in Eclipse, linking to the project I want to test, creating an activity and there using some of those classes. Unfortunately, I get NoClassDefFoundError. Could you please address me to the right direction on how to create this kind of test?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is JUnit testing. [There](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/522312/best-practices-for-unit-testing-android-apps)  [is plenty](http://marakana.com/tutorials/android/junit-test-example.html)  [out there](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/testing/testing_android.html)  [to get](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/testing/helloandroid_test.html)  [you started.](http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/android-unit-testing)

To test activities you can fire intents using [ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/test/ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2.html)

Comment: I've already read about junit, but it seems to me quite complex. No simpler way to do this? I just want to include the classes of a project in another one (without having to mark the first as a library). Thanks anyway for your answer!

Comment: Yes there are many ways you can go about this. Its best if you dont modify the code to be tested for the sake of testing. You can create a test class and fire intents from that test class to your target class. Or just import the target package and use it, It all depends on your implementation. JUnit is pretty simple once you get it working.